# FileMaker SQL Count Rows when Grouped by Calculated MonthYear

Tags: sql, filemaker

Trying to work out the following and think I've tried every combination of COUNT GROUP HAVING WHERE ORDER I can think of and no luck.

Have one table with these columns:

```
Date     MonthYear      JobStatus       JobType
```

**final Output i need based on above table columns:**
The Result I'm looking for is the number of rows in each MonthYear/JobStatus GROUP, WHERE the JobType is "X" and the Date is in between 2 dates. Oh, and it needs to be ORDERed by Date ASC.

**what have i tried so far:**
So I tried all sorts - but to my mind the logical approach is:

```
SELECT MonthYear, JobStatus, Count(*)
FROM Jobs
WHERE Date > '5/1/15' AND Date < '9/31/15' AND JobType = 'X'
GROUP BY MonthYear, JobStatus
ORDER BY Date ASC
```

**Expected output:**

```
May 15|Ready for Submission|1
May 15|Submitted to b|1
May 15|Approved|10
Jun 15|Ready for Submission|1
Jun 15|Approved|46
Jun 15|Submitted to b|11
Jun 15|Submitted to a|1
Jul 15|Submitted to a|1
Jul 15|Submitted to b|13
Aug 15|Submitted to b|36
Aug 15|Chasing Paperwork|1
Aug 15|Submitted to a|2
Aug 15|Approved|2
Sep 15|Chasing Paperwork|1
Sep 15|Submitted to a|2
```

But this just results in an error. Any help greatly appreciated - been at this for the last day and a half now!!

Comment: what is the error you are getting,i dont see any issues with your query

Comment: Well when FileMaker evaluates it I just get "?"

Comment: I've got the error description now: All non-aggregated column references in the SELECT list and HAVING clause must be in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: That means you are not posting your entire query

Comment: This is the full expression from FileMaker: `sql.debug ( ExecuteSQL ( 


"

SELECT ScheduledMonthYear, JobStatus, COUNT(*)
FROM Jobs
WHERE ScheduledDate > '5/1/15' AND ScheduledDate < '9/31/15' AND JobType = 'OLEV Grant Installation'
GROUP BY ScheduledMonthYear, JobStatus
ORDER BY ScheduledDate ASC

" ; 


"|" ; "¶" 

 ) )`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to TheGameiswar I looked for the error description which led me to find the hidden sql.debug function. Quick google of the error code and the first result describes that you can't use GROUP and ORDER in the same query. Guess GROUP does the sorting. This is in FileMaker at least, which has it's own unique implementation of SQL. Couldn't speak to any other version. So the resulting query that works is:

```
SELECT ScheduledMonthYear, JobStatus, COUNT(*)
FROM Jobs
WHERE ScheduledDate > ? AND ScheduledDate < ? AND JobType = ?
GROUP BY ScheduledMonthYear, JobStatus
```

Comment: My only issue now is that the resulting list is ordered alphabetically by the Month name.. which is still a problem.

Comment: For now, as I don't see there being any easy way to do this in SQL, have changed the MonthYear to result in 20165 instead of May 16, which can be ordered correctly.